# angularjs filter Dropdown options by object properties

Tags: javascript, angularjs, filter

I can't seem to find the way to filter my options in my drop down.

```
<div>
    <select>
        <option ng-repeat="draw in draws| filter:{draw.perform == true && automatic == false}">

        </option>
    </select>

</div>
```

data looks like :

```
{
   automatic: true,
   date: 1417388400000,
   drawQuantity: 0,
   number: 1,
   offer: {
      image: "/"test,
      number: 1
   },
   perform: true
}
```

I get the data from firebase, that's why i need to do filtering on frontend. If anyone was wondering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax is incorrect. Try this instead:

```
ng-repeat="draw in draws| filter:{perform: true, automatic: false}"
```

If you need to filter by property values you should use [object notation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter).

Comment: Actually found out that I should use ng-options instead of an option with ng-repeat :)
But thanks for the help, your solution did work as well, so I'll put it as correct one

Comment: Geez, can't believe I didn't notice that you were using `ngRepeat` instead of `ngOptions`. But the principle of using filter object is the same anyway.